# Safe to use pressure cooker for beer stew?

Tags: pressure-cooker, stews

I was thinking of using a pressure cooker to prepare the Flemish rabbit. This requires stewing the rabbit legs in beer.

Is it safe?

Comment: Why do you think it would not be safe?

Comment: Who knows?... https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84310/why-would-boiling-milk-in-an-electric-kettle-break-the-kettle or https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68715/carbonated-beverage-in-pressure-cooker

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly safe to add beer to any recipe in a pressure cooker. (well, any recipe you might use beer for outside a pressure cooker). While I've not done this with rabbit I have with venison (for chili), beef and chicken for various stews.

Assuming your concern is adding a 'carbonated' beverage, this question has been answered here: [Carbonated Beverage in Pressure Cooker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68715/6279)

Indeed one may easily find a plethora of [beer in a pressure cooker](https://www.google.com/search?q=pressure%20cooker%20recipes%20with%20beer&oq=pressure%20cooker%20recipes%20with%20beer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.6644j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) recipes like [these](https://www.yummly.com/recipes/pressure-cooker-and-beer).